# more than one requested posted to server (retrofit)

Tags: android

I am using retrofit to post the request to server but it is posting data twice. I have checked code, I made only on call. I know retrofit trying to connect server again and again until it connected or timeout but if once data posted to server and I get the response from server than why retrofit making again call for the same.

```
 Call<LoanSaveResponse> call = apiService.saveLoan(loan);
    call.enqueue(new retrofit2.Callback<LoanSaveResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoanSaveResponse> call, Response<LoanSaveResponse> response) {
            customProgressBar.stopProgressBar();
            Log.e(" response", new Gson().toJson(response));

            if (response != null) {
                if (response.body() != null) {
                    // Showing Alert Message
                    showDialog(response.body().loan_id);

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoanSaveResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            customProgressBar.stopProgressBar();
            Log.e("Failed", t.toString());
        }
    });
}

public class ApiClient {
/*http://172.16.40.1:8080/loyalty/*/
//:http://54.83.7.62:8080/loyalty/userAnswer
 private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();


        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(GlobalBaseUrl.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;

}
```

}

Comment: please provide your code that you are using

Answer (score 0):

For Retrofit 2

Define a listener in your web service instance:

```
public interface OnConnectionTimeoutListener {
    void onConnectionTimeout();
}
```

Add an interceptor to your web service:

```
public WebServiceClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.setReadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            return onOnIntercept(chain);
        }
    });
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
    webService = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
}
```

Enclose your intercept code with the try-catch block and notify the listener when an exception happens:

```
private Response onOnIntercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    try {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        String content = 
 UtilityMethods.convertResponseToString(response);
        Log.d(TAG, lastCalledMethodName + " - " + content);
        return;
response.newBuilder().body
(ResponseBody.create
(response.body().contentType(), content))
.build();}

catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
        if(listener != null)
            listener.onConnectionTimeout();
    }

    return chain.proceed(chain.request());
}
```